# Unable to save large text in mysql thru php

Tags: php, mysql, longtext

```
$query="INSERT INTO `ARTICLES` (`TITLE`, `BY`, `IN`, `POST`) 
VALUES('". $title ."', '". $by ."', '". $in ."', '". $_POST['post'] ."')";
```

This code is able to save small length text but not large. The datatype for the `POST` field is longtext.
Also if i insert data thru phpmyadmin, it gets saved.

Comment: Make sure you escape the `$_POST['post']` data properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query="INSERT INTO ARTICLES (TITLE, BY, IN, POST) VALUES('$title', '$by', '$in', '". $_POST['post'] ."')";
```

Use this query, and modify the database field's property to BLOB text using PHPmyAdmin.

I works for me when i need to insert large contents.

Comment: better to use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: hmm. its better. but i didnt know about it.

Answer (score 6):

like Felix kling says you need to escape your post data because maybe there are some quotes in the text you try to save but it will prevent your query to run properly and it is also a major security risk not to escape before sending to the database.

```
$post = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']);

$query="INSERT INTO `ARTICLES` (`TITLE`, `BY`, `IN`, `POST`) 
VALUES('". $title ."', '". $by ."', '". $in ."', '". $post ."')";
```

also make sure you've set the `POST` column to text in phpmyadmin. Because if you didn't prepare enough space it won't save to the database.

Answer (score 0):

To insert data in a Database always use a [PreparedStatement](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)! Never trust the users input!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use mysqli_stmt::send_long_data : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php . There are some good examples in manual/comments.